# Counting odd digits

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $k,n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $n>1$.

Converting $k$ in a base $n$,

$$ k=  n^ln_{ l} + n^{l-1}n_{l-1} +\cdots+ nn_1+ n_0$$

$$=(n_{ l} ~ n_{l-1} ~\cdots~  n_1~ n_0)_{n} $$

If base $n$ is odd  and $k$ is even then there are  even times odd digits present in $k$.

And if base $n$ is odd  and $k$ is odd then there are  odd times odd digits present in $k$.

**Example**

$$231 = (22120)_3$$
$$=(1411)_5$$
$$=(450)_7$$

And

$$128=(11202)_3$$
$$=(1003)_5$$
$$=(242)_7$$

> **Question**
>
> > How to determine for which even base $n$ have odd times odd digits and even times odd digits are there in given $k$

more simply

Definition

Let D be the function , function define as follows

$$D(n,k)=r$$

Where $$D(n,k)=n_0+n_1+...+n_{l}$$

For  example
$D(5,17)=5$.

I already proved

$D(odd,odd)=odd$

$D(odd,even)=even$

$D(2,$ Evil numbers$)=even$

$D(2,$ Odious numbers$)=odd$

[Evil numbers](https://oeis.org/A001969)

[Odious numbers](https://oeis.org/A000069)

> Here my question
>
> > given $k$ and $n$ is even and $D(n,k)=r$ then how to determine $r$ is even or odd with respect to $n$?

Comment: 2 mod 4 k may work.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee can you explain in more detail

Comment: in any 4k+2 base any number that doesn't fill the ones place with an odd ( using a 4l digit) but has an odd number of odd digits is 4j+2. actualy found an error, the only odd digits that matter are the 4k+2 and 1's place.